# After Installing Hyper V Windows 10 detects extra generic PnP monitors

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, hyper-v

After enabling Hyper-V on my Windows 10 laptop I have 5 extra generic pnp monitors detected in my display settings panel and in my device manager. When I remove the Hyper-V feature these monitors are gone.

When I now connect an extra display to my HDMI port and I want do duplicate my second screen is never on a same display number. So today I extend display 1 and 6 but tomorrow it can be 1 and 5.

I am using a Dell Precision M2800

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Based upon [past experience](https://superuser.com/questions/1152547/windows-10-sees-much-more-monitors-than-i-have/1152608#1152608), this is typically caused by a a display driver.  Try checking online for a newer one, and if that doesn't resolve the issue, try on older version.

Comment: But when I remove hyper-v I only see 1 monitor. So clearly Hyper-V is doing something strange here.

Comment: Perhaps Hyper-V is a contributing factor that serves as a catalyst to reveal the underlying problem.  I could be wrong, but every time I have previously encountered this problem the display driver fixed it.

Comment: @danny-h I can confirm that I have the _exact_ same problem as you. I enabled hyper-v this morning, and now I have extra monitors appearing, seemingly in random quantities and in a random order. Updating display drivers (for both Intel HD Graphics 4000 and AMD FirePro W4170M) does not resolve the issue. Turning off hyper-v does, however (which is unfortunately a non-fix -- i need hyper-v on since I'm trying to use docker for windows).

Comment: @danny-h scratch that -- updating the drivers using Windows 10 device management doesn't resolve the issue, but grabbing drivers directly from the manufacturer's website (Dell, in my case, and the Intel drivers specifically) _did_ fix it. The driver installer noted that it was installing an older version than was currently installed -- maybe the newest version of the drivers has an incompatibility / bug when mixed with hyper-v? Unsure.

Comment: Problem came back for me with a windows update. Using the current set of drivers on Dell's website doesn't fix it.

Comment: This also happened to me - installed Hyper-V and after the required reboot I have phantom monitors

Comment: @toby1kenobi, if this also happened to you and the accepted answer solved your problem, it might be prudent to comment and/or up-vote accordingly rather than author an entirely new question & answer pertaining to the exact same problem.

Comment: I deleted my question for you, but this question here (that you're asking me to now participate in) has also been marked a duplicate, by five different people!

Comment: @toby1kenobi yes, it is technically labeled as a duplicate, but I am the person who posted the appropriate answer in both of them.  However, as you strongly emphasized within your deleted question, the original one didn't specifically mention Hyper-V as the catalyst for the problem.  This question **did** and already had an accepted, viable solution which solved the problem.  You saw that *before* you created your "new" question/answer.  Once again, that is deceptive and unprofessional, at best.

Comment: I had the same issue with Lenovo Ideapad Y510P, I installed latest driver for Intel Graphics HD 4600 which I downloaded from Intel.com website. now the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that the problems comes-and-goes with Hyper-V is certainly a new factor in the equation.  However, on the other occasions that I have seen this multiple monitor problem happen before, it is usually caused by the display driver.

Faced with the same scenario, I would [manually create a System Restore point](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4571-system-restore-point-create-windows-10-a.html) as a potential fall-back and then check for an updated graphics driver to install.  If you are already running the latest version, try dropping back to an older version and see if it alleviates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comment off @dvlsg I tried to update the Intel Graphics HD 4600 video drivers for my Dell Precision M2800 with the drivers provided on the Dell support page. After installing the drivers provided by Dell the problem is gone.

Comment: I am certainly glad to hear that your problem has been resolved, but I am a bit curious as to how your self-accepted answer differs from what I suggested?

Comment: I don't know if it is specific to Intel driver so I specified details in my anwser. Your anwser is also correct but I can not accept two anwsers.