# Monitor display issues after enabling hyper-v by installing Docker

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, docker

I'm having issues extending my main display to my external monitor. I didn't have this issue until after I enabled hyper-v by installing Docker.

After restarting my computer to enable hyper-v, the "Customize your display" page in Windows 10 is telling me that I have 4 displays. I would post an image if I had higher reputation, but I'll try to explain through text.

For my main display, it says it's "1|3". Then my other displays are represented as "2", "5", and "6".

Any idea on how to fix this?

**EDIT**: I found a hackey way to solve this--but I don't think I want it as the main solution.

1. Duplicate the display you want to other monitors you don't want. For example, you would click "Duplicate desktop on 1 and 4." This should join your desired display with another one.
2. After duplicating the display you want to keep (`Display 1` in this answer), click "Display only on 1."
3. Replicate this process until all the displays you don't want become disconnected.

Is it possible to get rid of the disconnected displays entirely? I'm still left with 6 displays when I only have two, but the other four don't affect my display now.

Comment: Did you tried clicking on 1|2 and changing from "Multiple display" menu below from "Duplicate desktop on 1 and 2" to "Extend desktop on 1 and 2"?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, just getting back to this. I disabled hyper-v (got my display to work after that), but now I'm trying to replicate the problem. Now it pops up as "3|4", "2", and "1". There are other inactive displays listed as "5" and "6."

Comment: I added an edit to my question. Is my "hackey solution" what you were talking about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem in this post: [Windows 10 sees much more monitors than I have](https://superuser.com/questions/1152547/windows-10-sees-much-more-monitors-than-i-have)  Basically rolled my Intel Display Driver 4600 back from version 20 to version 10 as per the post.  This solved the problem.

Comment: I have noticed some side effects since rolling the display driver back.  My wallpaper on my primary monitor seems zoomed in - it's as if it calculated the monitor width to be the total width of both my primary and secondary monitors.  I also noticed that fonts in some applications (line SSMS and Visual Studio) are sometimes quite blurred, but then come right when I scroll the affected window.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the driver of the 4600 adapter also works.